# Problem getting the userName from jwtToken

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt

I implemented security for my application using JWT tokens. I make a post request to the /auth endpoint (passing userName and password) and get back a token, which I then use for further requests to the other endpoints. Everything works perfectly fine, but I can't get the userName out of this token. Here' my controller method:

```
@GetMapping(produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<List<SongList>> getSongListsForUser(@RequestParam("userId") String ownerId) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String userId = auth.getName();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userId.equals(ownerId)
            ? songListDAO.findListsOf(userId)
            : songListDAO.findPublicListsOf(ownerId));
}
```

Found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063348/spring-mvc-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-securitycontextholder-when-trying-t) on stackoverflow.

I put a breakpoint at the line of the return statement to inspect whats inside the userId and got this:

[image]

Why this is not working? What do I have to do to get the userName (=userId) from the jwt token?

Comment: if you could show the token (with test data, no sensitive information) as text instead of an image, we could see if the information is available in the token.

Comment: Ok, no problem - nothing sensitive yet here: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtaWthXzY2NiIsImV4cCI6MTYxNzAwOTA3MSwiaWF0IjoxNjE3MDA1NDcxfQ.MyOWUAo-WpLy4eLwd2QuSw8x2FMhWYDnyO83o4o4q0VAbxoUjaqzZ9RYJdHodVvNXsf-NvVyzC6QoBOzFKtpjQ. UserId is inside the token - already checked this...